# Global Outlook email footer

Tags: email, images, exchange, footers, exchange-online

We use exchange online and would like to set global email footer image.

Can you provide a solution to host the image internally or best practice to have it hosted externally (e.g on a website)?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for the email footer you mentioned, [organization wide signatures and disclaimers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/create-signatures-and-disclaimers?view=o365-worldwide) can be set in exchange online. However, adding embed images is not supported.

So I'm afraid that you need to create a signature and add a logo or image to your signature in Outlook client. For more information: [Create and add a signature to messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.